# Add function to single blog post pages only

Tags: posts, functions, filters

I am wanting to add this code to single blog posts only after content. Right now it is showing up on every page after content.

```
add_action( 'presscore_after_content', 'insert_cp_banner' );

function insert_cp_banner() {
    rcblock_by_id( "8301" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the check for a single post:

```
if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {

 add_action( 'presscore_after_content', 'insert_cp_banner' );
}
```

See this for details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
add_action( 'presscore_after_content', 'insert_cp_banner_after_content' );

function insert_cp_banner_after_content() {

    $banner_id = '1111'; //Use the default banner if not a single post type

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        $banner_id = '8301';
    }

    rcblock_by_id( $banner_id );
}
```

With this approach, you can effortlessly include various banners based on the post type or page and have a fallback option to use a default banner when needed.